# server client application in android

Tags: android, tcp, client-server

I am trying to develop an application in android in which users will be able to share their location information with other users they choose. Firstly i tried to make it a database driven application but it was a bit though for me .
Now i decided to make it client server application in which there will be one server and multiple clients. When the client opens the application, it will connect to the server over TCP. The server will keep track of which users have connected. Then when a client user want to share its location information, it will able select among these list (list will be passed to the client by the server.) 
but with this approach i have this issue:
how can i track or keep each user's unique info on the server. One solution maybe is to use the i.p. numbers, but there maybe multiple clients connected through same i.p. for example from a campus network. (my system will be tested in such a network).
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution could be this...

Create a registration form in your android app. You can ask them to enter their cell number (which will be unique) or you can fetch IMEI number of the device and store it in server using an SQL OR NO-sql db (Raven, Mongo, couch etc). and using it as a unique key you can keep track of all the clients...

did i miss something ?

Comment: thank you. i did not know about imei numbers. i assume i can get the imei number of the device in client side, and pass it to the server side. in the server side, a thread will be created for each client. i can use this number to assign a thread id maybe. i will try to it that way for now.

Comment: my pleasure. Please let me know your findings.